# Webpack and svgstore, how?

Tags: webpack, vue.js

Im trying to configure Webpack to output an SVG sprite using [svgstore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-svgstore-plugin)

However, im a bit stuck and cant get it to work...
My webpack config is based on webpack-simple from the vue-cli

All my svg files are stored in `"src/assets/svg/"` - and I want it to output the svg sprite to `/dist/` folder....

At the moment, no SVg's are compiled to a sprite when running `npm run build`

My webpack file looks like:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var SvgStore = require('webpack-svgstore-plugin');
var sourcePath = path.join('src');

module.exports = {
entry: './src/main.js',
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
},
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader',
            options: {
                loaders: {
                    // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
                    // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
                    // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
                    'scss': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader',
                    'sass': 'vue-style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
                }
                // other vue-loader options go here
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
                name: '/img/[name].[ext]?[hash]'
            }
        }
    ]
},
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
},
devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true
},
performance: {
    hints: false
},
devtool: '#eval-source-map',
plugins: [
    new SvgStore(
        path.join(sourcePath, 'assets', 'svg', '*.svg'),
        'dist',
        {
            name: 'sprite.[hash].svg',
            chunk: 'src',
            svgoOptions: {
            }
        })
]
```

}

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
// http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV: '"production"'
        }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: true,
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
        minimize: true
    })
])
}
```

Comment: Any Progress on this? I am searching for the same ;)

Comment: You can check [webpack-concat-svg-plugin](https://github.com/rimlin/webpack-concat-svg-plugin), which easy integrate and use

Comment: I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-spritemap-webpack-plugin easier to use with VueJS